# Confused about ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a database table called "Warehouse" this Warehouse's linked to a "Product" table (1 to many relationship). How do I in *ASP.NET MVC*:

1. Create a warehouse view/page with the total number of products in this warehouse displayed
2. On the same view/page display the product id and name and qty as textfields (allow editing) prepopulated
3. On the same view/page have a save bottom. if clicked will save all the changes

Is it possible in ASP.NET MVC? How do you go about it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [**NerdDinner tutorial**](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm).  It goes into detail exactly how to do the things you described, with generous code samples.